# Laravel generate multi level dynamic menu with unlimited submenus array

Tags: laravel, menu, many-to-many, laravel-8, multi-level

I have been struggling to find solution in order to make a multi level dynamic menu with unlimited submenus (just like wordpress) I have checked other solutions but cant seem to find one that creates a proper collection/array of the data.

**HOW THE DB STRUCTURE LOOKS LIKE?**

**1. TABLE: app_page**

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | app_id | page_id | parent_id |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 |       1 | NULL      | 2021-04-20 19:58:21 | 2021-04-20 19:58:21 |
|  2 |      1 |       2 | NULL      | 2021-04-20 19:58:21 | 2021-04-20 19:58:21 |
|  3 |      1 |       3 | 2         | 2021-04-20 20:01:04 | 2021-04-20 20:01:04 |
|  5 |      1 |       4 | 3         | 2021-04-20 20:01:09 | 2021-04-20 20:01:09 |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**2. TABLE: pages**

```
+----+--------+--------+------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | title  | active | visibility | label | data |     created_at      |     updated_at      |
+----+--------+--------+------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Page 1 |      1 |          1 |     0 | NULL | 2021-04-20 19:57:15 | 2021-04-20 19:57:15 |
|  2 | Page 2 |      0 |          1 |     0 | NULL | 2021-04-20 19:57:15 | 2021-04-20 19:57:15 |
|  3 | Page 3 |      0 |          1 |     0 | NULL | 2021-04-20 20:01:04 | 2021-04-20 20:01:04 |
|  4 | Page 4 |      0 |          1 |     0 | NULL | 2021-04-20 20:01:07 | 2021-04-20 20:01:07 |
+----+--------+--------+------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**WHAT ARE THE RELATIONS?**

In my **APP** modal i have the following many to many relationship for pages:

```
public function pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Page::class, 'app_page', 'app_id', 'page_id')
        ->withPivot('parent_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

**WHAT IS THE REQUIRED OUTPUT?**

According to the table, the above data should output something like this, i will just use page titles as an example:

```
[
    0   =>  [title: Page 1],
    1   =>  [
        title: Page 2,
        children: [
            0   =>   [
                title: Page 3,
                children: [
                    title: Page 4
                ]
            ],
            .... can have more records and their children also
        ],
    ]
    .... can have more records and their children also
]
```

Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Comment: Can anybody please help me solve it?